# radio button read only without fading

Tags: html

Is it possible to make a radio button **read only** without fading ?

Comment: What's the point in displaying a normal looking user-interface element that the user can't interact with? This is very bad UX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As most of the people before, I don't really see a good use of it, but if you need it, here's a hack:

Include [jquery](http://jquery.com/) javascript on your page and add class attributes to your radios:

```
<input checked="checked" name="n" value="1" type="radio" class="rdonly checked" /> 
<input type="radio" name="n" value="2" class="rdonly"/>
```

And add the javascript hack:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input.rdonly").change(function() {
    $('input.checked').attr('checked', true);
  });
});
```

this will make all the radios with "checked" class instantly become selected when a user tries to select any radio with "rdonly" class. It looks just like was read only, but not faded.

I hope this is what you're looking for, but then again, I think I'd advise against it.
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you can't control it. It is up to browser unfortunately.

And poeple on the Web are used to the style of the disabled fields, changing it wouldn't that much ***accessible*** (or standard) any way.

Comment: You could do a JavaScript hack to keep it set on/off as required, but I'd personally say that's just making a bad idea worse. :-)

Comment: @middaparka: Agreed, it wouldn't be as per accessibility principles either :)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery :

```
$('#radio-id').change(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

But like others said, I don't see the point, and I don't think it's a good idea...